# Вопросы/квадраты вместо русских букв в MySQL базе данных

Tags: java, mysql, кодировка, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте. Делаю тестовый проект с аутентификацией VK на Spring MVC, вытаскиваю имя и фамилию пользователя на русском языке в переменную, а затем через JDBC Template передаю в базу. В консоли Eclipse имя фамилия выводится нормально, а в БД только вопросы/квадраты.
Квадраты, если делаю вот такое:

```
String s = user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName();
userName = new String(s.getBytes(), "UTF8");
```

Вопросы, если второй строчки не делаю.

Что уже сделано:

**В БД:**
В таблице прописано charset:utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci

команда SET NAMES utf8mb4

**В проекте**
В настройках jdbc соединения прописано `jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8`

В конфиге добавлен фильтр

```
    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter[] filters;

        CharacterEncodingFilter encFilter;
        HiddenHttpMethodFilter httpMethodFilter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();

        encFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

        encFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        encFilter.setForceEncoding(true);

        filters = new Filter[] { httpMethodFilter, encFilter };
        return filters;
    }
```

Что еще можно посмотреть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Надо было прописать не

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

а просто

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8
```