# Установить кодировку form либо request

Tags: html, mysql, servlet

Есть форма:

```
<form method="post" action="/masks" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Когда из request'a вытаскиваю параметры и записываю их в MySQL вместо русского текста кракозябры.

Как исправить проблему?

`UPDATE` информацию из ссылки на другой пост учел и использовал, проблема осталась

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вопросы/квадраты вместо русских букв в MySQL базе данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727193/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2-%d0%b2-mysql-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: какая база данных?

Comment: База данных MySQL

Comment: Самый простой вариант не иметь проблемы с кодировками - это везде использовать одну и ту ж кодировку, желательно utf-8